# Writing Case in MDX query?

Tags: ssas, mdx, ssas-2008

I have an MDX code like this,

```
({[Ping].[ID].&[20] : [Ping].[ID].&[200]})
.
.
```

I have to write it with the use of Switch/Case statement.

This is what I done, but something is missing, not working.

```
WITH MEMBER [Ping].[ID].[FORMAT2] AS     
CASE     
WHEN [Ping].[ID].&[10]    
THEN [Ping].[ID].&[100]    
WHEN [Ping].[ID].&[20]     
THEN [Ping].[ID].&[200]    
ELSE [Ping].[ID].[FORMAT]    
END
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHEN [Ping].[ID].&[10]
```

is not a condition. The WHEN statements inside a case need to be a condition that evaluates to true or false.

Something like

```
WHEN [Ping].[ID].CurrentMember IS [Ping].[ID].&[10]
```

or something similar.

Comment: It would be much better to use `WHEN [Ping].[ID].CurrentMember IS[Ping].[ID].&[10]` than `WHEN [Ping].CurrentMember.Name = [Ping].[ID].&[10].Name`. You compare member identity with `IS`.

Comment: True, you're right. I edited the answer to reflect your suggestion. Thanks.